# Maven build removes configured access restriction rules

Tags: eclipse, maven

I'm using Eclipse 4.4 Java EE with maven. I need to work with some methods that are marked as restricted. So I configured the required access restriction rules in eclipse. An everything's working.

But then I run Maven/Update Project and after that all the previously configured rules are gone. So the question is: how to tell maven about the rules?

Comment: This is an IDE specific configuration which is not the intention of Maven and not supported as far as i know. In this case i would recommend to define checkstyle rules which will work independent from the IDE in the build and fail the build if someone violates the rules. This is a more general solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the methods are restricted due to the Java execution environment that Maven configures on your project (e.g. you want to use Java 7 methods while the project is configured for a Java 6 execution environment), then you should configure the Maven compiler plugin in the POM to use the Java version that you want to use (e.g. via the maven.compiler.source and maven.compiler.target) properties.